# Handle NULL in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT item.`ID`, item.`Name`, item.`UnitCost`, 
       item.`Price`, discount.`rate`
FROM item 
INNER JOIN discount ON discount.`ID`=item.`DiscountID` 
WHERE item.`Code`=itemCode;
```

If `discount` is not assign to the `item` (MEANS NULL), the above query does not return any row.

How can Change my query to handle `null`? and in case of `null`, `item.discountID` must be return 0?

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: ok @eggyal thanks for fruitful link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT item.`ID`, item.`Name`, item.`UnitCost`, 
       item.`Price`, IFNULL(discount.`rate`, 0)
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN discount ON discount.`ID`=item.`DiscountID` 
WHERE item.`Code`=itemCode;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from the first table, even if there are no matches in the joined table.

Comment: dear, yes working but one thing more discount.rate is equal to (NULL) , I want to show here zero (0) , if it null. What Changes made are required? @Stardev

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner join. Try a left join or right join imstead when you have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Do it with LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT item.`ID`, item.`Name`, item.`UnitCost`, item.`Price`, discount.`rate` 
FROM item LEFT JOIN discount ON item.`DiscountID`=discount.`ID`
WHERE item.`Code`=itemCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **LEFT JOIN** instead of INNER JOIN. INNER JOIN just return rows when there is at least one match in both tables

**COALESCE()** will convert all the null values to 0

try this

```
SELECT item.`ID`, item.`Name`, item.`UnitCost`, 
       item.`Price`, COALESCE(discount.`rate` , 0)
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN discount ON discount.`ID`=item.`DiscountID` 
WHERE item.`Code`=itemCode;
```